# Remove option from select control with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Can't get this piece of code to work. The purpose is to remove an option called Motorhome from a select control based on if the area C is selected from another select control.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Area').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'C') {
                $("#camping-unit option:[value='Motorhome']").remove();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$("#camping-unit option[value='Motorhome']")` `:` is causing the malfunction

Comment: Thanks, such a silly mistake!

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$("camping-unit").removeAttr("value")
```

Comment: It's all good, the problem has been resolved. Thanks for responding anyway!